# Assigning Tasks to Entities (or some other entity) based on Priority

Tags: python, algorithm, heap, priority-queue

**Main Questions:**

- Is my runtime analysis correct?
- Is my approach optimal or close to it?
- Is there a better way and/or improvements?

**Objective:**

- Write an algorithm to assign `n` jobs to `k` entities (servers, cpus, whatever) in a round robin fashion. The job that takes longest will be assign first, the shortest last. In the case of a tie, the job with lowest id will be assigned first.
- return the job ids assigned to each entity, where an entity can be represented as a list

sample input:

- `jobs= [40, 80,40, 4, 2]`
- entities = 2
- where `jobs[i]` is the length of time the task, and `i` is its identifier.

sample output:

- [[1, 2, 4], [0, 3]]

I came up with two algorithms and wanted to see if my runtime analysis is correct, and if there is a better way to approach this

#### Implementation 1: Linear Search

**Pseudocode:**

- linear search for the longest job, from left to right, saving its job id (index)
- only update the index if we find a larger job in list
- once we find it assign to another list, which will contain the jobs in order
- iterate over the ordered list, assigning to each server in round robin fashion

**Hypothesis for runtime:**

- time proportional to `n ^ 2`, where `n` are the number of jobs

**Code**

```py
def findMax(jobs):
        ind_of_max = 0
        ### iterate over jobs
        for k in range(len(jobs)):
            # if current job we are processing is greater than the previous lomgest job
            if jobs[k] > jobs[ind_of_max]:
                ind_of_max = k
        # sinonimouns to removing the job from the PQ
        jobs[ind_of_max] = -1

        return ind_of_max

def determineJobOrder(jobs):
    
    # list of jobIds
    order_of_jobs = []
    num_of_jobs = len(jobs)
    
    #### TOTAL RUNTIME ANALYSIS:
    # - runs in time proportional to N  ^ 2
    ####

    # runs in time proportional to N
    while num_of_jobs > 0:

        # removing jobs from list (aka performing dequeue operations until we run out of jobs)
        # runs in time proportional to N
        ind_of_max =  findMax(jobs)
        
        order_of_jobs.append(ind_of_max)      
        num_of_jobs -= 1
     
    return order_of_jobs

def assignJobsToServers(servers, jobs):
    
    jobs = determineJobOrder(jobs)
    
    # create a list of lists, where the number of inner lists = number of servers
    assignment = [[] for i in range(0, servers)]
    
    
    num_jobs = len(jobs)
    job_ind = 0
    server_ind = 0
    

    ###
    ### RUNTIME ANALYSIS:
    # - runs in time proportional to n
    #while there are jobs left to assign

    while num_jobs > 0:

        assignment[server_ind % servers].append(jobs[job_ind])
        # update server index, job index, and number of jobs left to assign
        num_jobs -= 1
        job_ind += 1
        server_ind += 1

    return assignment
```

#### Implementation 2: Using Heap

**Pseudocode:**

- Iterate over all jobs, creating a Job object, Job(job_id, time)
- Since python's `heapq` class is a min heap, I use `heapq.nlargest`, passing a key for comparison, the list of Jobs

**Hypothesis of runtime:**

- time proportional to `n log n`, where n are the number of jobs

**Code:**

```py
## To enncapsulate the jobs and be able to compare by multiple attributes
class Job:
    def __init__(self, job_id, time):
        self.job_id = job_id
        self.time = time

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Job(id: {}, time: {})'.format(self.job_id, self.time)




import heapq



def assignJobsToServers(servers, jobs):
    
    for k, exec_time in enumerate(jobs):
        jobs[k] = Job(k, exec_time)

    
    # resource used to figure out how to sort by two attributes, one in natural order one in reverse:
    # https://www.techiedelight.com/sort-list-of-objects-by-multiple-attributes-python/
    
    #### Runtime Analysis:
    # - I am assuming that what this will do is build the max heap, and then remove the n items to get them in max order.
    # - Inserts into heap take log (n).
    # - removals take log(n)
    # - if we are enqueueing n items, this will take n log n
    # - if we are removing n items, this will take n log n for removals
    # - hence: runtime should be proportional n log n, ignoring constants
    ####

    # key defines that that the larger the time the larger the, and on a tie, the smallest the job id the largest the item 
    jobs_ordered = heapq.nlargest(len(jobs), jobs, key = lambda job: (job.time, -job.job_id))


    # create a list of lists, where the number of inner lists = number of servers
    assignments = [[] for i in range(0, servers)]
    
    
    num_jobs = len(jobs)
    server_ind = 0
    job_ind = 0
    
    ###### RUNTIME ANALYSIS:
    # - at this point we already did all the difficult computation. We now just iterate over all jobs which will be in order and assign
    # - this takes time proportional to n, the number of jobs
    while num_jobs > 0:
       
        assignments[server_ind % servers].append(jobs_ordered[job_ind].job_id)
        
        # update server index, and number of jobs left to assign
        num_jobs -= 1
        server_ind += 1
        job_ind += 1

    return assignments
```

Answer (score 1):

Your runtime analysis seems fine and your heap-based approach is optimal in the
narrow sense that it achieves `O(n log n)` performance. However, the software
itself is needlessly complex.

The path to simplicity is found by remembering the most famous `O(n log n)`
operation: **sorting**. You have a list of job durations that you
want to sort from largest to smallest, breaking ties via their ID/index. There
are a variety of reasonable ways to achieve that. Here's one illustration:

```
# Some job durations and a generator to produce (DURATION, ID) pairs.
durations = [40, 80, 40, 4, 2]
pairs = enumerate(durations)

# A function to take a pair and return a modified pair for sorting purposes.
sort_key = lambda pair: (-pair[1], pair[0])

# Sort the pairs and extract job IDs from them.
job_ids = [jid for jid, dur in sorted(pairs, key = sort_key)]

# Allocate the job IDs to N workers/entities in round-robin fashion.
n = 2
allocated_job_ids = [job_ids[i::n] for i in range(n)]
print(allocated_job_ids)   # [[1, 2, 4], [0, 3]]
```

Comment: got it. not sure why that did not come to mind but that would definitely be simpler in this case, Thank you. Would a PQ implemented with Heap be preferred in the case our list of jobs is not static , meaning, let's say, two jobs can be added to the initial list, then 1 remove, followed by more additions and removals interleaved? it seems like in that case we couldn't achieve n log n for both removals and additions. What do you think?

Comment: @MPC Correct. The superpower of a heap is its log-n ability to maintain sorted order in the face of inserts/removals.